# Is it possible to create inconsistent Data in onCreate() function?

Tags: java, android, function, oncreate

I have a small question about the Data consistence in the `onCreate()` function. For better understanding my example:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    public String isThisConsistent1;
    public int isThisConsistent2;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.Test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Item_1:
            getSomething();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Test);

        /*Very, very long taking code like a huge loop */

        isThisConsistent1 = ...;
        isThisConsistent2 = ...;
    }

    private void getSomething(){
        String test1 = isThisConsistent1;
        int test2 = isThisConsistent2;
    }
}
```

So my question is: Is it possible to click the Item on my ActionBar before the `onCreate()` function is finished? Because then I would call the function `getSomething()` before the Data was set in the `onCreate()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle), the `onCreate` method is called before view is visible. This means, the answer is no, you can't click the button before the `onCreate` finishes.